# VS2017 Web Services parameter getting object not set error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I wrote a Windows Forms application in Visual Studio using C# as an ordering system for our production plant. I am trying to implement an SAP web service to create Transfer Orders for the warehouse to know what material to deliver.

I used Visual Studio 2017's native Add Service Reference to import the WSDL.
I have tested the web service in SOAP and it works.

I am trying to add the required fields, the quantity field has a unit code that goes along with it. In SOAP it looks like this.

```
<RequiredQuantity unitCode="PCE">10</RequiredQuantity>
```

In Visual Studio I instantiated my transfer order and the request and I'm trying to add the parameters, but I keep getting Object Reference not set to the Instance of an Object.

```
private void btnOrderPallet_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) //ops leader tab
        {
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.UseWebServices == "Yes")
            {
                try
                {
                    QOE_CreateTO.TransferOrderCreate_InClient transferOrder = new QOE_CreateTO.TransferOrderCreate_InClient("HTTP_Basic_soap12");
                    transferOrder.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "blah blah";
                    transferOrder.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "blah blah 123";

                    QOE_CreateTO.TransferOrderCreateRequest toRequest = new QOE_CreateTO.TransferOrderCreateRequest();

                    //working
                    toRequest.WarehouseID = "98W";
                    toRequest.MaterialNumberID = "7516000796";
                    toRequest.PlantID = "982W";
                    toRequest.StorageLocationID = "ADPP";

                    //not working
                    toRequest.RequiredQuantity.unitCode = "PCE";
                    toRequest.RequiredQuantity.Value = 10;

                    //not working either
                    var qty = toRequest.RequiredQuantity.Value;
                    var uc = toRequest.RequiredQuantity.unitCode;
                    qty = 10;
                    uc = "PCE";
                    toRequest.RequiredQuantity.unitCode = uc;
                    toRequest.RequiredQuantity.Value = qty;

                    //not working either
                    var rQty = toRequest.RequiredQuantity;
                    rQty.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(10);
                    rQty.unitCode = "PCE";
                    toRequest.RequiredQuantity = rQty;

                    //working
                    toRequest.SourceStorageTypeID = "801";
                    toRequest.SourceStorageBinID = "02-01-01";
                    toRequest.DestinationStorageTypeID = "PSA";
                    toRequest.DestinationStorageBinID = "PSA_REMAN";
                    toRequest.UnloadingPointName = "Reman Line";
                    toRequest.MovementTypeCode = "919";
                    toRequest.AutoCreationIndicator = true;

                    transferOrder.CreateTransferOrder(toRequest);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error(...);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                
            }
        }
```

Thanks to @JHBonarius requested more detail, here is the get/setter from the object browser.

```
public partial class RequiredQuantity : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
        
        private string unitCodeField;
        
        private decimal valueField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType="token")]
        public string unitCode {
            get {
                return this.unitCodeField;
            }
            set {
                this.unitCodeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("unitCode");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public decimal Value {
            get {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set {
                this.valueField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
        
        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

and from the Public partial class:

```
        /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=4)]
    public RequiredQuantity RequiredQuantity {
        get {
            return this.requiredQuantityField;
        }
        set {
            this.requiredQuantityField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("RequiredQuantity");
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: something's clearly not working... but it's not in the code you show. i.e. if we cannot reproduce your problem we cannot help you. You should consider making a [mcve].

Comment: Well what isn't working is the toRequest.RequiredQuantity.unitCode immediatly returns object not set to instance of the object. So there's something about the way I am setting unitCode and Value or the way it's instantiated is different than the rest of the parameters. I'll read the link you sent next....

Comment: Yes, indeed. But it's not in the code you show us... So it's a bit hard for us to point it out for you....

Comment: @JHBonarius I worked through the article. The code above is both minimal and reproducible per the guide. Only portion not complete is the service reference imported by VS2017. According to the stacktrace the problem is at the line I mention. Maybe I"m just not understanding you, but I don't understand what you are saying is missing. #irony

Comment: I'm afraid you're not understanding the article. Especially the part "Provide *all* parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem". You just show us some snippet of code that gives you the error. We have no way to reproduce that error this way. 
And maybe in the process of recreating the minimal reproducible example, you will already discover your problem.

Comment: Imagine you going to the apple store and ask them to tell you what's wrong with your iPhone... and you only show them a picture of the phone... Can they help you in that case?

Comment: @JHBonarius I've provided the full code on the button. I hope it's helpful. I have a feeling it won't provide any additional assistance. I really do appreciate you taking the time to try though!

Comment: But the problem is that `RequiredQuantity` is `null`... and that property should probably be filled in the constructor of `QOE_CreateTO.TransferOrderCreateRequest`. But you're not showing that. The error occurs in the code you show, due to something (not) happening in code you don't show. That's what's meant with 'being complete'. And to prevent you having to share /all/ the code, we prefer 'minimal'.

Comment: Ahh okay that's because I didn't create that code. It's auto generated when I imported the WSDL using VS2017 native Add -> Service Reference. I have edited back to minimal as I had before. Yes, I am stuck as well not having created the code for the constructor.

Comment: maybe there's an error in the wdsl, which causes the import to skip the initialization of the property.

Comment: @JHBonarius One more try here. Does the additional info above help?

Comment: I would guess that the `RequiredQuantity` object should be initialized in the constructor of `QOE_CreateTO.TransferOrderCreateRequest`, but it isn't. Maybe that's an error, but I don't know the framework will enough. You could create the object yourself,  i.e. `toRequest.RequiredQuantity = new RequiredQuantity();` before you use it... note that all the other properties are value type and the new one is reference type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the WSDL creation has created an 'object' for the property you are trying to set to.

```
public partial class RequiredQuantity : object
```

this seems to indicate that you need to instanciate this object before assignment to the property it contains.

Try:

```
//set object first
toRequest.RequiredQuantity = new RequiredQuantity();
toRequest.RequiredQuantity.unitCode = "PCE";
toRequest.RequiredQuantity.Value = 10;
```

or if it can't resolve the new reference, use the inbuilt tools to track down what namespace that object is under. This then should allow you to set the properties. What's happening is that it appears that you are trying to set a sub property of an uninstanced object hence the "object not set error".

The others work, because they are simple strings and contain no sub objects so the WSDL creator can make them as simple base types. This one is more complex and so needs to be created before assignment.

Comment: This worked! Thanks also to @JHBonarius as he suggested it as well. Thank you!

Comment: @FullStackDeveloper If this answer helps you handle the issue, you can click `√` to mark it.